# How to delete an entity by property in gae datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
Key newwordKey = KeyFactory.createKey(NEWWORD_KEY_KIND, NEWWORD_KEY);
Entity newWord = new Entity(NEWWORD_ENTITY_KIND, newwordKey);
newWord.setProperty(USER_COL_USERNAME, userName);
newWord.setProperty(NEWWORD_COL, word);
datastore.put(newWord);
```

I mean I want to delete all "newword" Entity by its property "username"
Ex, delete all words upload by user "Alexis"
Any idea ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Delete Entities by Query function:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(NEWWORD_KIND.class);
q.setFilter("USER_COL_USERNAME == USR");
q.declareParameters("String USR");
q.deletePersistentAll("Alexis");
```

[More info here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Deleting_Entities_by_Query)

Hope this helps.